# Python, Django: Query on combined models?

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

inside my app I have multiple *models*, like:

**models.py:**

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)


class Coworker(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, blank=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

As you can see, a *Company* can contain one, multiple or no *Coworker*! Is it possible to query *Company* but also receive the data from connected *Coworker*? For example something like this:

```
id    |    Company    |    Coworker
1     |    Company_A  |    Coworker_A
2     |    Company_B  |    
3     |    Company_C  |    Coworker_B
4     |    Company_C  |    Coworker_C
5     |    Company_C  |    Coworker_D
6     |    Company_D  |    Coworker_E
7     |    Company_D  |    Coworker_F
8     |    Company_E  |    
9     |    Company_F  |    Coworker_G
10    |    Company_F  |    Coworker_H
...
```

My problem is, that I can't query on the *Coworker*, because I don't want to miss those *Companies* that have no related data!

Thanks for your help and have a great day!

Comment: Use the filter method, if there is no coworker for that company it will return empty list []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simply, query by company and prefetch results for workers :

```
Company.objects.prefetch_related("coworker_set").all()
```

What this will do is give you a list of companies containing their list of workers in the attribute `coworker_set`. It will also populate those attributes in a single query (that's the whole point of `prefetch_related`).

More specifically, here is how you could use such a query :

```
for company in Company.objects.prefetch_related("coworker_set").all():
    print(company.name)
    for coworker in company.coworker_set.all():
        print(coworker.first_name)
        print(coworker.last_name)
```

This guarantees that you will iterate through all companies as well as through all coworkers, and you will only iterate through each one once (indeed, if you queried by coworkers you would see some companies multiple times and others none at all).

Comment: Thank your very much, especially for the extra content! Helped perfectly!